# NSTimer invalidation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

If I create a timer which never repeats

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateSystems) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

do I still need to invalidate it?

Also, is releasing the instance one step in the invalidate method? Since I'm not using alloc my timer variable shouldn't have to be released, although when creating a timer it automatically should create a new thread? Does the timer still add up on the stack? 
I need some clarity.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation for the method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-CHDECCEE).  It says:

> *repeats*
>       If YES, the timer will repeatedly reschedule itself until invalidated. **If NO, the timer will be invalidated after it fires**.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that if I close the app before my timer has fired, the timer seems to be stored until when I open the app again. So how can I cancel the timer if it has not been fired. By using invalidate?

Comment: if(timer != nil)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }

in applicationDidEnterBackground seems to take care of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating any pointer to NSTimer. You are using it directly through a class method. This method does not creates a new instance of NSTimer so you don't have to release it.

Comment: +1 Apart from mis-spelling NSTimer :-) this is a very good point.  Although you are effectively creating an NSTimer object (the timer is returned by the method), you do not own it, so you should not release it.